# iOS Content Blocking Extension Loading Multiple JSON Files

Tags: ios, swift, safari-content-blocker

Is it possible to return multiple JSON files from a **Content Blocker Extension**? In my UI users enable / disable different filters and each filter is represented by a separate file. I currently have (which only loads one despite iterating through multiple):

```
func beginRequestWithExtensionContext(context: NSExtensionContext) {
    var items = Array <NSExtensionItem>()

    let resources = ["a", "b", "c"]
    for resource in resources {
        let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(resource, withExtension: "json")

        if let attachment = NSItemProvider(contentsOfURL: url) {
            let item = NSExtensionItem()
            item.attachments = [attachment]
            items.append(item)
        }
    }
    context.completeRequestReturningItems(items, completionHandler: nil)
}
```

I've tried doing multiple items and a single item with multiple attachments. If it isn't possible to have separate files, any way to combine multiple (or generate programmatically)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those curious I ended up adding code to dynamically generate a JSON file (persisted to disk). From other answers it seems like the step of saving could be avoided by returning an `NSData` representation of the file instead - although that attempt failed for me. Here's my snippet:

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices

class ActionRequestHandler: NSObject, NSExtensionRequestHandling {

    func beginRequestWithExtensionContext(context: NSExtensionContext) {
        let item = NSExtensionItem()
        let items = [item]

        let url = buildJSONFileURL()
        if let attachment = NSItemProvider(contentsOfURL: url) { item.attachments = [attachment] }

        context.completeRequestReturningItems(items, completionHandler: nil)
    }

    func buildJSONFileURL() -> NSURL {
        let directories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let directory = directories[0]

        let path = directory.stringByAppendingFormat("/block.json")

        let selector = [...] // Dynamically Generated
        let dictionary = [[
            "action": [ "type": "css-display-none", "selector": selector ],
            "trigger": [ "url-filter": ".*" ]
            ]]

        let data = try! NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictionary, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
        let text = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)!

        try! text.writeToFile(path, atomically: true, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)

        return NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you. tried your code, didn't work. i'm not sure how do you combine or split json files here according to the filter ...

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to have multiple JSON files and use it for the Content Blocker extension.

1) Throws `SFContentBlockerErrorDomain` when you pass multiple extension items to `completeRequestReturningItems` method.

2) Can't attach multiple attachments to `NSExtension`. The comment on the source code says, the attachment is not meant to be an array of alternate data formats/types, but instead a collection to include in a social media post for example. These items are always typed `NSItemProvider`. I reckon you wouldn't be able to add multiple JSON data as attachments, since they are not a series of attachments to create a message.

My Solution (Verified it works):

`NSItemProvider` can be initialised with item (NSData) and `typeIdentifier`.

```
let aData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("a", withExtension: "json")!)
let bData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("b", withExtension: "json")!)

aJSON = `convert aData to JSON`
bJSON = `convert bData to JSON`
combinedJSON = `aJSON + bJSON`
combinedData = 'convert combinedJSON to NSData'

let attachment = NSItemProvider(item: combinedData, typeIdentifier: kUTTypeJSON as String)
```

Now you could create the extension with the attachment, `combinedData` as per your preferences.

Comment: I'm a beginner here.  Could you point me to an objective-c version of this?  Thanks

Comment: Find the implementation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43827031/using-multiple-json-lists-in-ios-content-blocker/52381166#52381166

Answer (score 1):

You can combine two JSON rule files in to one file and use that file.

```
    import UIKit
    import MobileCoreServices
    class ContentBlockerRequestHandler: NSObject, NSExtensionRequestHandling {

        func beginRequest(with context: NSExtensionContext) {

        let sharedContainerURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "you app group identifier")

                let sourceURLRules = sharedContainerURL?.appendingPathComponent("Rules1.json")
                let sourceURLRules2 = sharedContainerURL?.appendingPathComponent("Rules2.json")
                do {
                    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()

                    let dataFormRules1 = try Data(contentsOf: sourceURLRules1!, options: .mappedIfSafe)// Rule is Decode able Swift class            
                   let  rulesArray1 = try? jsonDecoder.decode(Array<Rule>.self,from: dataFormRules1)

                    let dataFormRules2 = try Data(contentsOf: sourceURLRules2!, options: .mappedIfSafe)
                    let  rulesArray2 = try? jsonDecoder.decode(Array<Rule>.self,from: dataFormRules2)

                    saveCombinedRuleFile(ruleList: rulesArray1! + rulesArray2!)

                } catch {
                    //handle error condition
                }

                let sourceURLCombinedRule = sharedContainerURL?.appendingPathComponent("CombinedRule.json")
                let combinedRuleAttachment = NSItemProvider(contentsOf: sourceURLCombinedRule)
                let item = NSExtensionItem()
                item.attachments = [combinedRuleAttachment]
                context.completeRequest(returningItems: [item], completionHandler: nil)
            }

            func saveCombinedRuleFile(ruleList:[Rule]) {
                let encoder = JSONEncoder()
                if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(ruleList) {
                    let sharedContainerURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "you app group identifier")
                    if let json = String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8) {
                        print(json)
                    }
                    if let destinationURL = sharedContainerURL?.appendingPathComponent("CombinedRule.json") {
                        do {
                            try  encoded.write(to: destinationURL)
                        } catch {
                            print ("catchtry")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```